# Javascript array creation

Tags: arrays

How do I turn this string: `house,33;car,43;dog's,99;` into this array: `arr[33]="house" arr[43]="car" arr[99]="dog's"` using javascript and jquery.

Once I have the array, can I store information (like a 0 or 1 flag) next to each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
var initString = "house,33;car,43;dog's,99";
var array1 = initString.split(';')
var result = [];
    for(var i=0,l=array1.length;i<l;i++){
        var items = array1[i].split(',');
        result[parseInt(items[1])] = {flag:0, value:items[0]};
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "house,33;car,43;dog's,99;";
var pieces = str.split(';');
var arr = new Array();
for (var index = 0; index < pieces.length; index++) {
    var halves = pieces[index].split(',');
    arr[ halves[1] ] = halves[0];
}
```

Though you really shouldn't be specifying the array index unless you have a complete list from 0 to 99 (your sample has only three entries, all of which are well into that sequence).

Comment: How could I store the number in some other way, associated with the word, but not as the index?